# The specified network name is no longer available in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have list of share path in a text file. I try to read the files and folders in each path and exporting to csv file using powershell script. I got some csv files with 0 KB. 
so i try to test the existance of such network path using Test-Path command. few  path shows it is exist but when itry to list out the directories of existing path using Dir \sharepath name i got error like "The specified network name is no longer available"  Why??

Sharing code below..

```
foreach ($dir in (Get-Content $infile)) {

$outfilecsv='jerin-Download'+'.csv'

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.* -Recurse | Select-Object 

Name,@{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-ACL $_.fullname).Owner}},CreationTime,@{Name="FileModifiedDate";Expression={$_.LastWriteTime}},

@{Name="FileAccessedDate";Expression={$_.LastAccessTime}},@{Name="Attributes";Expression=

{$_.Attributes}},@{l='ParentPath';e={Split-Path $_.FullName}},

@{Name="DormantFor(days)";Expression={[int]((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).TotalDays}},

@{N="FileCategory";E={Get-FileSizeCategory($_)}},

@{Name="Size";Expression={if($_.PSIsContainer -eq $True){(New-Object -com  

Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFolder( $_.FullName).Size} else {$_.Length}}}|

Export-Csv -Path $outfilecsv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation

}
```

Can anyone suggest

Thanks
Jerin

Comment: You'll need to share your code to get any useful advice.

Comment: Sir,Please see the edited question with my code

Comment: I don't see a test-path in there. How are you checking the paths?